# share the current user in application views

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a .net core application with a SSO authentication. I need that my controllers and views be aware of the currently authenticated user.

I built a service, in witch I obtain the base information from the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` load from there custom user info:

```
public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor context) => _context = context;

    public IApplicationUser GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var name = _context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher
        {
            Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={name}))"
        };
        SearchResult userProperty = ds.FindOne();

        ApplicationUser currentUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = userProperty.Properties["mail"][0].ToString(),
            UserName = userProperty.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString(),
            Nom = userProperty.Properties["sn"][0].ToString(),
            Prenom = userProperty.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString()
        };
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

I inject that service in the base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserResolverService _userService;
    public BaseController(IUserResolverService userService) => _userService = userService;

    public IApplicationUser CurrentUser
    {
        get { return _userService?.GetCurrentUser(); }
    }
}
```

So, now, any controller knows the current user (if any).

Now how to pass that CurrentUser on the view...? I tried to build this class

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public IApplicationUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
}
```

and to pass it to the `_Layout` as model

```
@model MyApp.Web.ViewModels.ViewModelBase
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- ... -->

<li class="nav-item dropdown open">
    <partial name="_LoginPartial" model="Model.CurrentUser" />
</li>
```

via the controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IUserResolverService userService) : base(userService) { }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModelBase model = new ViewModelBase() { CurrentUser = this.CurrentUser };
        return View(model);
    }
```

but is not good, cause there are a lot of views that uses different model classes...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I injected the service in the view directly, without the controller

```
@inject IUserResolverService userService

@{ var currentUser = userService.GetCurrentUser(); }
```